# Xojo HTMLviewer Raspberry Pi3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, webkit, xojo

I'm developing an app for Windows and raspberry pi using Xojo. I'm relying on the HTMLviewer heavily in places to render web driven content.

I have multiple Raspberry Pi 3s, reading the xojo documentation I can see that HTMLViewers are not supported on Jessie. However, I cannot run Wheezy as it will not run on the pi3 due to kernel support for ARMv8.

I have tried using Ubuntu mate on the Pi and using sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0.0, however this does not work as Ubuntu has deprecated 1.0.

I'm looking for suggestions as to how I can get the HTMLviewers working on Raspberry Pi 3. I'm open to any suggestions OS versions etc. The PI will only be used for the custom app.

Many Thanks

Comment: Post this question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/